# django type error,object of type 'ModelBase' has no len()

Tags: python, django

my views.py:

```
def songs(request):

    object_list=song_thumb.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(song_thumb, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        artists = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        artists = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        artists = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'page':page,'artists':artists})
```

my pagination.html and home.html

```
<div class="pagination">
  <span class="step-links">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
          <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
          Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if page.has_next %}
          <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
      </span>
    </div>

#home.html
<div class="container">


  {% include "pagination.html" with page=page_obj %}


  </div>
```

I am getting a typerror.It shows that object of type 'ModelBase' has no len
Tracebacks:
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
E:\coding\fyp\music\home\views.py in songs
artists = paginator.page(page) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py in page
number = self.validate_number(number) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py in validate_number
if number > self.num_pages: …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py in num_pages
if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page: …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py in count
return len(self.object_list) …
▶ Local vars

Comment: Shouldn't `aginator = Paginator(song_thumb, 3)` use `object_list` instead of `song_thumb`?

Comment: Yup that fixed it.thank you

Comment: However the links to the pages are not appearing

Comment: the `page=page_obj` does not make any sense, since you never passed a `page_obj` to the template, only `page`.

Comment: the page=page_obj is in my main template.I am including the pagination template in the main template.

Comment: exactly, and where in the context is there a `page_obj`?

Comment: In the pagination template the {%if page has next%} should be if page_obj has next.similarly everything that where there is page in the pagination template should be replaced by page_obj.But for my own convention i take page_obj as page.The page=page_obj is to tell django to take all instances of page as page_obj

Comment: no, you just should remove the `with page=page_obj`. The context variable is `page`, hence there is no need to assign something else to `page`.